# Is it possible to run queue with schedule:run command? If yes then how?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, schedule, laravel-8

I'm creating a job for emailing like this:

```
$this->dispatch(new SendEmailJob(
    $request->email,
    $request->subject,
    $request->content)
);
```

And want to run only one command that will handle both schedule and queue.
Is it possible?

Comment: have you tried? should be a question you can answer yourself

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to run only one command that will handle my cron jobs as well as queue jobs
Like for queue i have to run  php artisan queue:work and for cronjobs need to run php artisan schedule:run
So is there any way i just run one command and laravel handle all schedule and queue?